# IE calc width issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, layout, microsoft-edge, calc

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ftqft005/1/

Basically, I want each red box of "stuff" to align beside each other, two to a row, with perfectly equal space to the left and right. So, "left stuff" goes on the left, "right stuff" goes on the right. I know if I change the width of .product-link from -7.5px to -15px, they go beside each other, but then the two boxes are not perfectly aligned in the center.

So basically, if I change this:

```
.product-link {
float: left;
background-color: red;
width: calc(99.99% * 1/2 - 7.5px);
width: calc(99.99% * 1/2 - 0.46875rem);
}
```

to this:

```
.product-link {
float: left;
background-color: red;
width: calc(99.99% * 1/2 - 15px);
width: calc(99.99% * 1/2 - 0.9375rem);
}
```

It sort of works, but it's not perfectly aligned like it is in Chrome and FireFox on the site. There's a little more space tot he right than there is on the left.

I'm not sure why it's not even working in the fiddle, because that same code does work for me in Chrome and FireFox, but breaks in IE and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it: https://jsfiddle.net/ftqft005/4/

Basically, I was trying to emulate this plugin: https://github.com/peterramsing/lost

Here's this person's code that I modeled mine after. It should give a symmetrical three item grid layout. I'm not sure if the clear is required, though.

```
div {
  width: calc(99.9% * 1/3 - (30px - 30px * 1/3));
}
div:nth-child(1n) {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
  clear: none;
}
div:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
div:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-right: 0;
  float: right;
}
div:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  clear: both;
}
```